# I need help visualising the font metrics in Wand

Tags: python, typography, wand

Normally when I write a sentence in Wand using `draw.text` the letter spacing is taken care of, however I need to write one letter at a time to build frames for a text animation. The problem with this is that by moving the left offset (here is the [documentation](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/wand/drawing.html#wand.drawing.Drawing.text) for the `draw.text` command) by `text_width`, given by `draw.get_font_metrics` the letter spacing is horrible.

I'm trying to use the other metrics provided to try and better calculate where to move the offset to have better letter spacing, however I'm having a hard time understanding what they mean.

The metrics are:

- `character_width`
- `character_height`
- `character_width`
- `ascender`
- `descender`
- `text_width`
- `text_height`
- `maximum_horizontal_advance`
- `bounding box: x1`
- `bounding box: y1`
- `bounding box: x2`
- `bounding box: y2`
- `origin: x`
- `origin: y`

Here is an example image with the metrics of the text:
[image]
The metrics for this text are:
`FontMetrics(character_width=150.0, character_height=150.0, ascender=140.0, descender=-29.0, text_width=133.0, text_height=172.0, maximum_horizontal_advance=527.0, x1=12.90625, y1=0.5, x2=54.296875, y2=78.65625, x=134.0, y=0.0)`

Apart from `text_width` which is really the width of the text in pixel, by calculating the dimensions of the text I see that for some reason `text_height` is the sum of the height of the two words, `character_width` and `character_height` are equal to the font that I chose in my code but the letters in the image are far from those dimensions, `maximum_horizontal_advance` is enormous and I have no idea what that could describe, `ascender` and `descender` seems too big for letters that don't stray much from the middle line of the text and the bounding box and origin coordinates don't make sense to me.

The closest visualization of this metrics that I could find was here http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#font_info however the numbers that I got from the code doesn't seem to fit this visualization.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could shed some light on this numbers and maybe suggest how I could use this metrics to have a better letter spacing than just incrementing the left offset in `draw.text` by `text_width`.

Thank you to everyone in advance!

The code that made that image is this:

```
from wand.image import Image, COMPOSITE_OPERATORS
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.color import Color
from wand.font import Font
import random, os

imgname = random.choice(os.listdir('/home/gionny/Downloads/HighResImg'))
text = 'Tr'
fontname = random.choice(os.listdir('/home/gionny/Downloads/font'))
with Image(filename='HighResImg/'+imgname) as i:
    i.resize(1500,1000)
    with Drawing() as draw:
        draw.fill_color = Color('#fff')
            #draw.stroke_color = Color('#000')
            draw.font_size = 150
            draw.font = 'font/'+fontname
            textWidth = int(i.width*2/3)
        textHeight = int(i.height*2/3)
        offsetLeft = (i.width - textWidth)/2
        offsetTop = (i.height - textHeight)/2
        metrics = draw.get_font_metrics(i,text,False)
        print(metrics)
            draw.text(x = int(offsetLeft), y = int(offsetTop + metrics.text_height/4), body = text)
        with Image(filename='logo.gif') as l:
                l.resize(80,80)
                l.transparentize(0.7)
                with Image(width=textWidth, height=textHeight, background=Color("skyblue")) as c:
                    c.transparentize(0.3)
                    draw.composite(operator='atop', left=i.width-90, top=i.height-90, width=l.width, height=l.height, image=l)
                    draw.composite(operator='atop', left=offsetLeft, top=offsetTop, width=c.width, height=c.height, image=c)
                    draw(i)
    i.format = 'jpeg'
    i.save(filename='script2.jpg')
```

Comment: Update: I figured out how to animate the nice image that I got with the `caption` command, avoiding all this impossibly complicated typograhical problems using `draw.text`. I used MoviePy which you can find here: https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/
Now I don't know how to put the question answered or even if I can with only this comment

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that `y2` is height of the letters from the origin. It is the bearingY in documentation.

`y1` is height below the origin.

[image]

[image: Documentation info]